# Delay signal according to normal distribution

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I am trying to delay a signal by a certain number of samples. This certain number, I would like to generate using a random normal distribution in Matlab. I am using the following for generating the number of samples *r = randn(1,1)/sampleTime*. This however generates negative numbers too. In order to avoid the negative numbers, I am taking the absolute value of *r* but I know that this is not the right way, since in this case I would be ignoring the left part of the distribution. Is there a way I can use just positive samples without shifting the mean too much?

Comment: A Gaussian distribution can produce arbitrarily large negative numbers (although with vanishing probability). You could shift the mean by an amount you consider to be acceptable, and use a _truncated_ Gaussian distribution: produce a random value acoording to the Gaussian distribution, and then reject the value if it happens to be negative (and in that case you need to generate a new value)

Comment: Why do you want to pull delays from a normal distribution? If you take the absolute value of the normal distribution you'll bias smaller numbers and the sample will no longer be centered at the mean of your distribution. Perhaps you are looking for a binomial distribution or a log normal distribution?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want an [exponential distribution](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Exponential_distribution)? The time between events is usually modelled as (decaying) exponential.

Comment: This is what my supervisor has mentioned  "Each clock should jitter according to a gaussian distribution function like:
http://www.aquaphoenix.com/lecture/matlab10/images-large/matlab_distribution_normal.jpg
but between -1 and 1 micro seconds" This jitter in my case translates to shifting the signal by as many samples with the sample time being 0.08 micro seconds

Comment: Your instructor wanted a jitter with both positive and negative values, why don't you just delay the positive delay values and crop the signal for negative delay values?

Answer (score 0):

For generating random events Poisson distribution fits your needs:
R = poissrnd(lambda) 
lambda is the mean parameter